# Getting TypeError on running nextjs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I am consistantly getting the following error when running my next server with npm run dev. I am almost certain it is not a problem with the code as i went back and ran it on a verified fully working project with the same result.

my thoughts are that it could be something to do with me running:

`npm install -g eslint babel-eslint eslint-plugin-react tern js-beautify`

but i ran an uninstall on those packages tried the server and still didnt work.

Here is the error message i am getting when loading localhost:3000

```
TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.DOM is not a function

App
./pages/index.js:7

   4 | import Explore from "./explore";
   5 | 
   6 | const App = (props) => {
>  7 |   return (
   8 |     <Fragment>
   9 |       <Explore />
  10 |     </Fragment>

processChild
/Users/nolanfreeman/Documents/dev/projects/Web_Apps/streamline/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3204:14
resolve
/Users/nolanfreeman/Documents/dev/projects/Web_Apps/streamline/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3124:5
ReactDOMServerRenderer.render
/Users/nolanfreeman/Documents/dev/projects/Web_Apps/streamline/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3598:22
ReactDOMServerRenderer.read
/Users/nolanfreeman/Documents/dev/projects/Web_Apps/streamline/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3536:29
renderToString
/Users/nolanfreeman/Documents/dev/projects/Web_Apps/streamline/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4245:27
render
/Users/nolanfreeman/Documents/dev/projects/Web_Apps/streamline/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:82:16
renderPage
/Users/nolanfreeman/Documents/dev/projects/Web_Apps/streamline/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:332:20
(anonymous function)
/Users/nolanfreeman/Documents/dev/projects/Web_Apps/streamline/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:797:21
asyncGeneratorStep
./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:5
_next
./node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27
(anonymous function)
/Users/nolanfreeman/Documents/dev/projects/Web_Apps/streamline/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:268:7
new F
/Users/nolanfreeman/Documents/dev/projects/Web_Apps/streamline/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:36:28
(anonymous function)
/Users/nolanfreeman/Documents/dev/projects/Web_Apps/streamline/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:257:12
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

edit: also have tried:

```
npm install --save react@16.12.0 react-dom@16.12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with your react DOM version. Try this:

```
npm install --save react@16.12.0 react-dom@16.12.0
```

Comment: appreciate the help, but still getting the same issue with multiple projects.

Comment: @NolanFreeman can you show your code? Because this is not enough to solve the problem

Comment: thats the thing i know it is not the code. i've even downloaded working nextjs app from github and the exact same issue persists.